# Foreach and Mysql in laravel views

Tags: php, pdo, laravel

I have got Laravel to work for doing simple HTML pages, routing worked, as defined at [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433683/using-css-in-laravel-views) but I am not sure how to get MySQL and PDO working in a view.

I can get 'traditional' Hello world PHP/MySQL queries working in a view, but am not quite sure how to do this with Laravel's framework.

I read through the documentation but couldn't find anything on how to do this - anyone got any ideas?

Currently I have a basic page, but want to get a simple foreach query working, echoing data from this table:

**testingdb**
Tablename: test1

```
name VARCHAR (255)
town VARCHAR (255)
biography TEXT
```

How would I get this to work without using the traditional PHP/MySQL methods that are normally mentioned in tutorials and using pdo instead (source, nettuts, why you should use PDO article)?

Is there something I need to do, create a controller etc?

Comment: Views should **never** contain any SQL. Direct interaction with database should not even be in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the answer in the documents  here http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent

to show you an example : 
1) first form your model ( eg . test1)
2) make a database table connection  and foreach like here:

```
foreach (test1::all() as $test)
{
     echo $test->name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that; as for the views, what do I do?

Comment: this code is in the view file ... check here there are some good tuts http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=859

Answer (score 0):

- Retrieving data: Here's [a good tutorial for Laravel's Eloquent ORM](http://daylerees.com/2012/04/04/laravel-eloquent-orm/).
- Passing data to views: See the relevant [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/views#binding-data-to-views) page.