# laravel routing css and js scripts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a laravel project and just wanted to use a simple timer jquery script in it. I created a new folder in views, placed there my code. I also placed there another folder called flip_timer with jquery files.
My problem is that i cannot make the script paths work "not found http exception".
Folder structure looks like this: folder in views > contains file(code below) and folder  including all the needed files. Whenever i try to run the link with code the page is empty, and when i click to see the source code and click on the css or js link it shows me the error i mentioned above...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flip_timer/jquery.flipcountdown.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="flip_timer/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="flip_timer/jquery.flipcountdown.js"></script>


<div id="retroclockbox1">
  <script>
    jQuery(function($){
    $('#retroclockbox1').flipcountdown();
})
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: See top answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232600/laravel-stylesheets-and-javascript-dont-load-for-non-base-routes

Comment: Just in case something happens to the link above, you need to store your assets (css / js) inside Laravel's `public` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your `jquery.flipcountdown.css` file in inside css folder named: `css/flip_timer/jquery.flipcountdown.css`
**AND**
your both js file inside js folder named:`js/flip_timer/jquery.min.js` and  `js/flip_timer/jquery.flipcountdown.js` and then put below code in your html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/flip_timer/jquery.flipcountdown.css') }}" />
```

**AND for js file**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/flip_timer/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/flip_timer/jquery.flipcountdown.js') }}"></script>
```