# how can i customiz the laravel 5.1 Login and register view pages?

Tags: laravel, gulp

im using the laravel 5.1 and building web app
i just bought HTML theme and directly copy all the css and Js files to public/assets ( not using any task runner such as gulp or grunt). i try to customize the login and register view page and if i use the default routing its fail to load the js and CSS ( just load plain HTML ) but if i point it directly by

`Route::get('login','AuthController@getLogin')`

**its working . how can i fix the JS and CSS problem ?**
*all the other pages works right and load the CSS and JS *

here are the screen shots from other pages and login page :
[image: other pages that is fine]

here is from my login page that fail to load :
[image: login page that cant load the style and scripts]

if i use route to directly link to the page not passing through the Auth controller and after submit send data to login function ( like simple normal forms) its working but if goes through the controller system its fail . also if i use :

```
    Route:resource('contact','contactcontroller')
```

my contact pages such as index, create , etc all are fail to load CSS but if i directly link to them like:

```
    Route:get('contact','contactController@index')
```

it will successfully load the CSS and my page will be shows fine .

Comment: how you add css and js?give an example

Comment: i just directly copy the CSS and JS files to public directory under the assets folder ( i made CSS and JS folder in assets folder ) . then just reference it directly one by one in my master layout : <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-extend.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.min.css">

Answer (score 0):

this question may help you with that ! 
[Laravel stylesheets and javascript don't load for non-base routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232600/laravel-stylesheets-and-javascript-dont-load-for-non-base-routes)

BTW : look at your page with firefox(chrome) Inspect Element Or Firebug to see the http requests!

Comment: i tried to use the firefox inspect in source code its looks fine ( no different with other pages ) ,but there is a major problem for those pages such as login and registration that can't load CSS or JS once click on the CSS link the left side window ( inspect window ) doesn't show anything but for other pages that able to load the CSS and JS it shows the CSS source code .       but in main page no different with the other pages .

Comment: do something ! in inspect windows click on network tab and click on reload! then check your requests for css and js files on each pages! maybe that help you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way script and style link

```
{!! HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') !!}
{!! HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') !!}
```

Comment: no, nothing changed , i already tried to load the CSS and JS in these ways : <link re=stylecheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">   also  {!! HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css')!!}  also <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">    .   all translate into right code in source code of the page and its works in all other pages but only not able to load in LOGIN and Register pages

Answer (score 0):

`<link href="{{URL::asset('../assets/css/bootstrap.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">`

`<script src="{{URL::asset('../assets/js/jquery.js')}}"></script>`

I use these methods works 10/10.