# Laravel 5 Hosting Asset Files

Tags: php, laravel

I have seen many questions here regarding Laravel 5 finding css and script assets. I have done what those answers suggest, mainly using a `blade.php` template and using either `asset()` or `URL::asset`, but sadly none of these work. I suspect something else is wrong here.

I am getting to my view directly, using `http://[MyIP]/[ProjectName]/resources/views/[MyFile].blade.php` in the address bar. My scripts and css are in the public folder, within directories `javascript` and `css` respectively.

When I load `[MyFile].blade.php`, which looks like so:

```
<title>My File</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/font-awesome.min.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/animatemolly.css')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/molly.css')}}">
        <script src="{{ URL::asset('javascript/jquerymin.js')}}"></script>
```

It finds none of those. And in the served page, I get this error:

`GET http://[MyIp]/[ProjectName]/resources/views/%7B%7B%20URL::asset('javascript/jquerymin.js')%7D%7D`

It's like w/e Laravel service should be converting these into something useful isn't running at all? Do I need to install something further? I was under the impression that using it this way came with Laravel 5, according to this answer: [Laravel stylesheets and javascript don't load for non-base routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232600/laravel-stylesheets-and-javascript-dont-load-for-non-base-routes)... so I must be having some other problem, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot go to your blade template directly, it must be rendered first by the templating engine. You usually do that in your controller.