# How to prevent URL structure from affecting jquery/javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, url, mediaelement.js

am building a small music site, and am using mediaelement.js , the following code replaces the default audio player with id="audio-player"

```
   $(function(){
        $('#audio-player').mediaelementplayer({
         alwaysShowControls: true,
         features: ['playpause','progress','volume'],
         audioVolume: 'horizontal',
         iPadUseNativeControls: true,
         iPhoneUseNativeControls: true,
         AndroidUseNativeControls: true
      });
   });
```

**PROBLEM**
When I use a url specifying just one folder like *mysite.com/folder1* it works fine but when I use a url with more sub folders like mysite.com/folder1/folder2 I get a **JS TypeError**

```
TypeError: $(...).mediaelementplayer is not a function
<anonymous>
noe:176
x.Callbacks/c()
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
x.Callbacks/p.fireWith()
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
.ready()
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
q()
```

Disclaimer: am not sure I asked the question right but if you understand the error properly, please help me edit the title. thanks in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code snippet shown, but with the path to mediaelement.js simply being wrong. You either need to modify the path for pages deeper inside the folder structure, or you simply refer it from the domain root, using a leading slash.

Comment: Thanks, am using laravel which has a folder from which resource files are referenced. Also there's a file(app.blade.php) containing url's linking to all resource files this file is then extended(called) in every other page. So I don't think I have a problem with url referencing.

Comment: Use your browser’s dev tools to find out whether the script could be loaded correctly or not. // Another possible reason could be, that `$('#audio-player')` simply doesn’t find an element in those pages; that can cause such an error as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks let me give that a try.

Comment: Hello @CBroe after investigation I found the files are not loaded.... But it happens only with url's of this structure what relation do they have?? thanks for your time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel stylesheets and javascript don't load for non-base routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232600/laravel-stylesheets-and-javascript-dont-load-for-non-base-routes)

Answer (score 0):

After making some research and using my browser dev tools to investigate as pointed out by *CBroe* in the comments. I noticed the files where not loading at all. Also I found **JS TypeError's occur when we try to make reference to undefined objects in one way or the other**. After noticing the files where not loading at all I could write a better search query which landed me on this SO question [Laravel stylesheets and javascript don't load for non-base routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232600/laravel-stylesheets-and-javascript-dont-load-for-non-base-routes) which solved problem. Hope this helps someone.