# How do i call css file in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Good day. I'm trying to call css in laravel. Here is the css url

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:84/mycms/public/css/index.css">
```

It's working fine.

Then I'm trying the `laravel way` with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16565640/6354277 . And i change it to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset(css/index.css') }}">
```

It Seems i can't found the css file. How can i fix it ?

Comment: you're `app` path is uncommon. seems like you need to modify `bootstrap` file.

Comment: The reason this isn't working is because Laravel expects you to set your web root to the public directory. If you inspect the page in your browser I would imagine the url in `href` is actually something **http://localhost:84/css/index.css**. What is your local set up i.e. Windows, Linux or Mac and are you using something like MAMP?

Comment: @RossWilson I'm using windows with xampp . ` 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost:84/mycms/public/'),`

Comment: `asset` just using the url from the current request and not your `APP_URL`. This post should help you set up your vhosts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-windows

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

My css file is in public/css/sample.css 
It works fine

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/sample.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
```

Comment: The `asset()` helper function will resolve the same path as `URL::asset()`.