# Laravel, right way to import javascript into Blade Templates

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.6. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232600/laravel-stylesheets-and-javascript-dont-load-for-non-base-routes) did not work for me.

pizza/index.blade.php looks like this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/pizza.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/components/pizza.js')}}"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Pizza</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="/pizzas" method="post">
                        @if ($errors->any())
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                Please fix the following errors
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        @include('pizza.table')
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

pizza/table.blade.php:

```
<div class="pizza-selection">
    <b>Thanks god its pizza day! Select your pizza of the day!</b>
    <table id="pizzas" class="md-box">
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
        @foreach ($pizzas as $pizza)
            ...
        @endforeach
        <tr>
            ...
            <input type="button" class="md-box btn btn-default" 
             id="add_new_pizza" onClick="addPizza()" value="Add Pizza!">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    ...
```

I get a reference error when I click on the "add_new_pizza" button, onClick="addPizza()", addPizza() is not defined. 
However, I try to import pizza.js in index.blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/components/pizza.js')}}"></script>
```

printing out asset('js/components/pizza.js') returns http://localhost:8080/js/components/pizza.js which looks right to me.

public/js/components/pizza.js looks like follows:

```
import PizzaService from '../services/PizzaService.js';

async function addPizza(){
    // some functionality
}
```

It also worked when I had the function addPizza() inside the script at .blade.php.

Also, find the repository on GitHub if you need any further code reviews:
https://github.com/andrelandgraf/laravel-docker

EDIT: When I copy the pizza.js inside `<script><script>` it works fine, but I receive a SyntaxError: `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`. This SyntaxError dissapears when I import the script via src like you can see in my code examples. For me, this indicates that the script is not loaded at all.

EDIT2 & Solution: I used @kerbholz solution. I added `@stack('scripts')` to the bottom of the `body` in `app.blade.php` and inside `@section('content')` of `index.blade.php` I know `@push('stack')` the `pizza.js` file.

I am now one step further but I still receive the SyntaxError stated in EDIT. Is there a workaround for that or do I just have to remove the import of `PizzaService.js` and add a `<scipt>-Tag` for this file as well?

EDIT3: Okay this issue is not related. It looks like ES6 modules are not yet supported by browsers.

Comment: Anything outside of your `@section` block will not be rendered.

Comment: @kerbholz thank you very much, I did not know that. I just started using laravel. I edited my question to fix this issue, however I still get the same error messaging.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Anything outside of your `@section` block will not be rendered.

You could edit your `layouts/app.blade.php` and add a `@stack('head')` where you want your styles/javascript to appear (preferably in the `<head>` section of your HTML).

In any blade file that `@extends('layouts.app')` you can then use

```
@push('head')
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/pizza.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/components/pizza.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

to push content into that stack.

For more information visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#stacks

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I edited my question and put the two scripts inside @section but I still receive the same error. When I try your solution, it disables my css and I receive the same error as before regarding the addPizza function. I also tried to add @stack('scripts') inside the app.blade.php head and pushed to scripts...

Comment: I usually have a `@stack('head')` in the head and `@stack('scripts')` at the end of the `app.blade.php`. The way I would do it is create a file `resources/assets/js/_pizza.js` and then `require('./pizza');` in my `app.js`. (And of course load `app.js` in  my `app.blade.php`)

Comment: Thanks for your supprt @kerbholz. It is now working for me. `push('scripts')` worked for me!

Comment: It is so annoying, that I cannot reach out to you directly via private message or something. Nevertheless, it was working for me, so I stopped thinking about it but I was wondering since I read your comment. How do you use require('./pizza') within laravel? Out of my knowledge, require is from nodejs and not available in plain js, right?

Comment: @Andre `require` is not available in plain JS, right. I think that's from `webpack`/[mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#working-with-scripts).

Comment: War mir ein Vergnügen ;)

Comment: import js file to head is a bad practice

Comment: That's why "_I usually have a @stack('head') in the head and @stack('scripts') at the end of the app.blade.php._" exists

Answer (score 14):

For custom scripts on specific page,

- add `@yield('footer-scripts'`) to `layouts/app.blade.php`
- create a folder named `'scripts'` in views folder
- inside `views/scripts` folder create a file '`pizza-script.blade.php`' and add the js file contents inside

  ```
  <script src="/path/to/pizza.js" />   <!-- it might not work if path isn't clear -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log('executing js here..')
     js file contents....

    #if jquery needed add it like, 

    $(document).ready(function(){
      ...
    }
  </script>
  ```
- in your index.blade.php (or the page where you want the scripts to execute) at the end add the script after `@endsection`

  ```
    @section('footer-scripts')
        @include('scripts.pizza-script')
    @endsection
  ```

now refresh the page, you can see `'executing js here..'` on the console.

Answer (score 2):

Try to move pizza.js at the bottom of **index.blade.php**

```
    @section('extra-script')

    {{Html::script('js/components/pizza.js')}}

    @endsection
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I have seen the Html:: before but it is not available inside the blade.php template. Where do you get the Html Class from?

Comment: Your config/app.php should contain following code in providers array

`'providers' => [
                       Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

]`

and aliases should contain

`'aliases' => [

                'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
                'HTML' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
]`

You can also add: <script src="{{ asset('js/components/pizza.js')}}"></script>

if html does not work.

Comment: I see Laravel Collective is another [package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html) that I do not have installed.

Comment: I used asset() now within your solution, I still receive the same error...

Comment: Sure thing but they do not really help: web console says: `ReferenceError: addPizza is not defined. onClick localhost:8080/pizzas:1:1`

Answer (score 1):

**To import a library from an external source** I wrote this small snippet. You add this in your layouts/app.blade in the footer below the footer scripts.

```
    @if(isset($externalJs))
        @foreach ($externalJs as $js)
            <script src="{{$js}}"></script>
        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Then in your blade you use it like this at the top of your file:

```
<?php
$externalJs[] = 'path/to/external.js';
?>
```

There could be other ways to do it but this is quick one for when you only have one file and dont want to import a librar

Comment: I usually use @section('scripts-bottom') <script></script> @append if you need to add scripts multiple times, maybe from components too, you should use "@append" instead of "@endsection"