# Laravel. Is webpack.mix.php the only way to run Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I was trying to add a simple character count to a textarea and it took me a day to get it working. I wanted to post what I learned and ask for clarification from any helpful users out there.

Laravel was not running javascript until I uploaded the script into *ProjectRoot/resources/js/app.js*.

```
var maxLength = 100;
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var length = maxLength-length;
  $('#chars').text(length);
});
```

Once the code is there I ran **npm run dev** (I have installed npm at this piont) and only THEN did the javascript run. The code is transferred into an app.js file in the *ProjectRoot/public/js/app.js* (which is a massive file where I couldn't find my code) directiory. I assume, and correct me if I'm wrong, this means npm run dev "converts" /"transfers" /"compiles" (what's the right word here?) the javascript to the laravel webmix system. This is where my knowledge and problem solving skills have puttered out.

Articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592054/laravel-right-way-to-import-javascript-into-blade-templates) and [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-make-a-character-limitcountdown-javascript-to-work-on-my-form) make it sound like I can just drop javascript into any xxx.blade.php file. Some other angles that did NOT work:

- importing .js files in the public/js directiory. No luck.
- `<script src="{{asset('js/count.js')}}"></script>` didn't work when I tried it in app.blade.php or the blade file with text area itself.
- including `*@section('script')*` didn't work either.

I'm getting the classic *Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined* in the chrome inspector console, but the countdown works so I I'm just not sure what's going on.

Can I run javascript inline in my xxx.blade.php with Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

in your blade file, where you want to use your script:

```
@push('js')
<script>
var maxLength = 100;
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var length = maxLength-length;
  $('#chars').text(length);
});
</script>
@endpush
```

and in your app.blade.php (your main blade where you include all the js/css files)

```
@stack('js')
```

Comment: Thank You! Where would you have gone to look this up? The push command is used to "append to a collection". Why do I need to append it to a collection?