# Laravel blade. Blade doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have route

```
Route::get("/prodByCat/{category_id}", "ProductController@productsByCategory")->name("product.productsByCategory");
```

and function

```
 public function productsByCategory($category_id){

   $products = Product::where('category_id', $category_id)->get();
   return view("cat", compact("products"));
```

in my template i have only

```
@extends("index")

    @section("content")
      @foreach($products as $product)
        {{ $product->name }}
      @endforeach
    @endsection
```

Problem is - links to bootstrap and custom css doesn't inherits. I tried to create another controller and new template file. But nothing works, except deleting {category_id} from Route. Why passing {category_id} conflicts with links to css files?

I tried composer dump-autoload and reboot computer.All other templates work properly.

```
My index template
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>@yield("title")</title>
    @yield("css")

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="files/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="files/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    @include("layouts._shopNav")

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          @yield('category')
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->

        <div class="col-lg-9">

          @yield("carousel")

          <div class="row">

          @yield("content")

          </div>
          <!-- /.row -->

        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="fixed-bottom py-3 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Some writing<br></p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="files/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="files/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the blade template file where you load your CSS etc.?

Comment: Ok. I posted template.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16565640/5523203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the wrong path of the css files. You can use

```
{{ asset('files/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}
```

to make sure that the path is correct.