# CSS file won't load in

Tags: html, css, laravel

My CSS file won't load in.

I've tried it with style tags but I don't like that

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/scss">`

Comment: your style sheet is `public/style/scss`?    watch out for relative pathing, you probably want to use a helper to get an absolute path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel stylesheets and javascript don't load for non-base routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232600/laravel-stylesheets-and-javascript-dont-load-for-non-base-routes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/file.css">
```

Comment: have to watch out for the relative pathing

Answer (score 2):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('style/scss.css') }}">
```