# CSS in Laravel 4.1.26

Tags: css, laravel-4, laravel-blade

When i tried to incude css and js in Laravel 4.1.26 ,it seems path mismach ,
Iput all the js and css inside

public\css\
public\js\

Here is my blade template files and details

app\views\layouts\master.blade.php

```
<title>dummy title</title>
@include('includes.css')
@include('includes.js')
```

app\views\includes\css.blade.php

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css'); }}
{{ HTML::style('css/css.css'); }}
```

app\views\includes\js.blade.php

```
{{ HTML::script('js/script.js'); }}
```

My problem is am not getting the exact path to css folders ,missing the public folder iin between , can anyone help me to solve this issue.
I saw some similar question in stack-overflow but hardly get the solution for this. So seems like a duplicate question but i didn't find a answer for this one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question contains the answers you need:

[Using CSS in Laravel views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433683/using-css-in-laravel-views)

However there seems to be another issue if you're needing `public` in your URL to access your site. The `public` directory should be set as the `DocumentRoot` and therefore you will not need to refer to that directory in your URL.

Comment: Is this is the solution? {{ HTML::style('public/css/index.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('public/js/jquery.pnotify.min.js') }}

Comment: Yes, that would work, but it seems like your server isn't configured correctly if you need `public` in the URL.

Comment: ok fine got it , so do you have any idea were will be the problem? It may very-helpful for me to continue

Comment: Not without further info which wouldn't be in the scope of this question.

Comment: No problem, the only extra thing I can say is to look at this section of the documentation - tells you how to use the built in server for development: http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation

Answer (score 0):

try this `{{ HTML::style( asset('css/css.css') ) }}`

Comment: Check you'r source code, and tell me what my first answer return please.

Comment: in both case first without assets and second with assets am getting same result as localhost/projectname/css/css.css