# I tried every way to use css in blade,but I failed,I need help!any tips or idea is ok

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

my project code is:   https://github.com/xsmyqf/hyhj.git
I was wrong to visit "localhost/hyhj/public/user/login".I failed to try every way to use css in blade,I need help,It seems that blade system did not give any response now.I want to know why I cannot use css in blade?notice that I have seen  [Using CSS in Laravel views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433683/using-css-in-laravel-views) ,and I tried the way in it,but it did not give any response!that is my headache,and when I tried to use  in blade,it did not give any response at all,I am crazy about this,It have wasted a day time,Must I substitute the blade with smarty?ah...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your blade files need to be named with *.blade.php. You called View::make('hello') and your file is called hello.php, try naming it hello.blade.php