# Laravel 5.4 cant find/load CSS or JS files

Tags: php, laravel-5

Before my question is flagged for duplication (did see similar questions), the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232600/laravel-stylesheets-and-javascript-dont-load-for-non-base-routes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433683/using-css-in-laravel-views) and few more failed to work in my case.

I just installed 5.4 and my css is not loading. First, to avoid public folder, i a using this .htaccess that i found somewhere

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /concurso_estagiario

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my app.blade.php, I have:

```
   <link href="{{asset('css/css.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

The CSS folder is correctly placed in public folder. The output shows:

alt, which hosts the laravel installation, is under htdocs. I even tried

```
 <link href="{{asset('public/css/css.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and still nothing. The resource is not being loaded at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'to avoid public folder'

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?